# Comparing a variable to multiple strings in Autohotkey

Tags: string, comparison, autohotkey

Often in my AutoHotkey scripts I need to compare a variable to several values values

```
if (myString == "val1" || myString == "val2" || myString == "val3" || myString == "val4")
    ; Do stuff
```

In most languages, there are ways to make this comparison a bit more concise.

**Java**

```
if (myString.matches("val1|val2|val3"))
    // Do stuff
```

**Python**

```
if myString in ["val1","val2","val3","val4"]
    # Do stuff
```

Does AutoHotkey have anything similar? Is there a better way to compare a variable against multiple strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many different ways.

- Autohotkey way ([if *Var* in *MatchList*](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm))

  ```
  if myString in val1,val2,val3,val4
  ```
- Similar to your java regex based way

  ```
  if (RegExMatch(myString, "val1|val2|val3|val4"))
  ```
- Similar to your python though not as nice way based on Associative Arrays

  ```
  if ({val1:1,val2:1,val3:1,val4:1}.hasKey(myString))
  ```

Comment: Notes about the 'AutoHotkey way': 1) Any spaces around the delimiting commas are significant 2) Matching is *not* case-sensitive by default

Comment: In its current form, regex will match `fooval1bar` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
; If-Var-In way. Case-insensitive.
Ext := "txt"
If Ext In txt,jpg,png
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"

; RegEx way. Case-insensitive. To make it case-sensitive, remove i).
Ext := "txt"
If (RegExMatch(Ext, "i)^(?:txt|jpg|png)$"))
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"

; Array way 1. Array ways are case-insensitive.
Ext := "txt"
If ({txt: 1, jpg: 1, png: 1}.HasKey(Ext))
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"

; Array way 2.
Extensions := {txt: 1, jpg: 1, png: 1}
Ext := "txt"
If (Extensions[Ext])
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"
```

If-Var-In is the most native way. However, you should be aware that it isn't an expression, and therefore it cannot be a part of another expression.

Broken:

```
SomeCondition := True
Extension := "exe"

If (SomeCondition && Extension In "txt,jpg,png")
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"
Else
    MsgBox,,, % "Bar"
```

Works correctly:

```
SomeCondition := True
Extension := "exe"

If (SomeCondition && RegExMatch(Extension, "i)^(?:txt|jpg|png)$"))
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"
Else
    MsgBox,,, % "Bar"
```

For the same reason (i.e. because it isn't an expression), you cannot you K&R brace style.

Works correctly:

```
Ext := "txt"
If Ext In txt,jpg,png
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"
```

```
Ext := "txt"
If Ext In txt,jpg,png
{
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"
}
```

Broken:

```
Ext := "txt"
If Ext In txt,jpg,png {
    MsgBox,,, % "Foo"
}
```